# How to attach instance of group of properties to objects

Tags: python, add-on, instances, custom-properties

I'm trying to attach instance of arbitrary collection of properties to newly created object.
For sure it's due to my lack of understanding of Blender, however I didn't find a way how to do it.

This is my code:

```
import bpy


class MyData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    myPath: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="My Path",
        default=""
    )
    check: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Check",
        default=False
    )


class MyCustomObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.my_custom_object"
    bl_label = "My Custom Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MyCustomObject")
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyCustomObject", mesh)
        context.collection.objects.link(obj)

        obj["MyData"] = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def AddMyCustomObject(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MyCustomObject.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyData)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyCustomObject)

    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(AddMyCustomObject)
    bpy.types.Object.MyData = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(AddMyCustomObject)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyData)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyCustomObject)

    del bpy.types.Object.MyData


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This is giving me following error:

```
obj["MyData"] = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)
TypeError: invalid id-property type _PropertyDeferred not supported
```

I also tried version using CollectionProperty instead of PointerProperty

The goal is to have custom object in the scene that can have their own data (string, number, boolean) that can be modified from UI and saved with the blender scene.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I'd like to clarify my original question.
I don't want to add MyData to every object I create. I want to add it only to objects created by MyCustomObject operator.

Comment: Then short answer is you can't add `PropertyGroup` as a regular UI property using the dictionary syntax (AFAIK). You may add a boolean flag to your property group and activate it in your operator, then use this flag to display or not your settings in your UI layout.

Comment: Lovely. Ok. Thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyData` already exists du to:

```
bpy.types.Object.MyData = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)
```

You can use it directly:

```
class MyCustomObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.my_custom_object"
    bl_label = "My Custom Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MyCustomObject")
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyCustomObject", mesh)
        context.collection.objects.link(obj)

        obj.MyData.myPath = "path" # <<<<<<<<
        print(obj.MyData.myPath)   # <<<<<<<<

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! 
I believe I tried this before and when I do that I'm not able to access the data on the object:
hasattr(bpy.context.selected_objects, "MyData")
is giving me False when I select the newly created object. 
So I guess my problem is in not understanding how to access it.

Comment: And I just answered myself... as I'm an $%^& :-) 
I'll try to differentiate between an array and object next time.
Thanks

Comment: I had to edit my original question a bit as this solution although working is not giving me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of your custom property group class is automatically added to all instances (existing and new ones) of `bpy.types.Object` in `register` after this line is executed :

`bpy.types.Object.MyData = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)`

The data is here, and you can access it as a member of `bpy.types.Object`. By default the values of the attributes of the property group will be the default values of the properties.

In your example, you don't need `obj["MyData"] = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyData)` which is used to add "simple" custom properties to objects. In this case this custom property slot is already taken by your property group so the script throws an error saying you can't overwrite it. The property group is already initialized. `obj.MyData.myPath` takes the default value of `""` and `obj.MyData.check` takes the default value of `False`.

You can display these properties in a layout element with `layout.prop(obj.MyData, "myPath")` and `layout.prop(obj.MyData, "check")`. You can get an example of how to setup a custoim panel in the *Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Simple Panel*.

Comment: I was a little bit late, it seems! ; )

Comment: hehe, *a wizard is never late, nor is he early, he arrives precisely when he means to* ;)

Comment: anyway in meantime the question has changed... to my knowledge that won't do...

Comment: Alright, well a fleeting question may only lead to fleeting answers. :)